# Count duplicate occurrences after time period or based on secondary column

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012

I currently have a table of access logs looking like this

```
LogID  UserID  BuildingID  Date/Time
===========================================
1      1       1           2013-01-01 10:00
2      2       1           2013-01-01 10:00
3      3       1           2013-01-01 10:30
4      3       2           2013-01-01 11:00
5      2       1           2013-01-01 11:00
6      4       1           2013-01-01 11:30
7      5       1           2013-01-01 11:30
8      5       1           2013-01-01 11:31
9      1       3           2013-01-01 12:00
10     1       3           2013-01-01 12:03
11     1       2           2013-01-01 12:05
```

What I need to do is create a query to count the number of duplicate user records based on the following 2 conditions:

1. A time difference greater than X minutes - X will be a parameter specified by the user
2. **OR** every distinct building for a user

For example, if I set the time difference to be 5 minutes then my results would be:

```
UserID   AccessCount
====================
1        3            <-- +1 for timediff (ID 1,10) +1 for building (ID 11)
2        2            <-- +1 for timediff (ID 2,5)
3        2            <-- +1 for building (ID 3,4)
4        1
5        1            <-- duplicate ignored because DateDiff < 5min
```

Hopefully that makes sense.

To give some background, this is for swipe access to some of our buildings and a business requirement came down for some analytical security reporting. Essentially we want to check access over given time periods for duplicates (typically done over weekends), but need to account for the fact that some of the swipe points fail and require a user to swipe multiple times. This is why I want the datediff as a swipe error would normally mean the user would swipe multiple times within a very short time.

Any help is greatly appreciated, thanks in advance!

Comment: SQL doesn't work "across rows" -- it optimizes within the row itself.  You would have to do some really funky joins and aggregations to get this to work.  I'd recommend, instead, having a job that iterates through the table and creates a new table that includes the fields you need, e.g. `TimeSincePreviousAttempt`.  Then the job only needs to incrementally crawl where `TimeSince...` hasn't yet been set for a given LogID.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can rephrase your logic by thinking of when you count a row and don't count a row.  You don't count a row when it is on the same building and within a certain period of the previous datetime on the same building.

I think this may be what you want:

```
select userId, count(*)
from (select LogID, UserID, BuildingID, dt,
             lag(dt) over (partition by userid, buildingid) as prevdt
      from t
     ) t
where dt > prevdt + TIMEDIFF or prevdt is NULL
```

In SQL, the a constant added to a date time is interpreted as number of days.  So, 5 minutes would be `(5.0/60)/24`.

You have no examples in your data, but if you had three rows:

```
1   1   1   11:30
2   1   2   11:31
3   1   1   11:32
```

Then this would not count row three because row 1 is covered by the first condition.

Comment: Thanks, this is exactly what I needed and seems to work perfect for all my test cases.

Comment: @Nathan . . . Glad I was able to help.

Answer (score 0):

Here's one approach:

```
declare @duplicateMinutes int = 5

select UserID, AccessCount = count(1)
from AccessLogs a
where not exists
  (
    select 1
    from AccessLogs d
    where a.LogID < d.LogID -- add this to try and avoid duplicate times cancelling each other
      and a.UserID = d.UserID
      and a.BuildingID = d.BuildingID
      and a.SwipeTime >= dateadd(mi, -@duplicateMinutes, d.SwipeTime)
      and a.SwipeTime <= d.SwipeTime
  )
group by UserID
order by UserID
```

[SQL Fiddle with demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/4b76e/5) - gives expected results for your data.